# Cutting a patch around a segment of a segmented image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have an segmented image into superpixels as follows:

```
from skimage.data import astronaut
img = astronaut()
segments_slic = slic(img, n_segments=250, compactness=10, sigma=1,
                     start_label=1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,8));
plt.imshow(mark_boundaries(img, segments_slic))
```

And got the following image:

[image]

I wish to cut a patch around each superpixel. Consider, for example, the patch around the shining part of the helmet colored red:

[image]

If I want to take a close (manual) look at the segments using `plt.imshow(segments_slic[425:459,346:371])`, I get this patch around the segment:

[image]

The pixels with the specific superpixel labe streach on row `425:459` and on columns `346:371`.

Currently, I am doing this:
patches = list()

```
for superpixel in np.unique(segments_slic ):
  x_min = np.min(np.where(segments == 15)[0]);
  x_max = np.max(np.where(segments == 15)[0]);
  y_min = np.min(np.where(segments == 15)[1]);
  y_max = np.max(np.where(segments == 15)[1]);
  patches.append(I[x_min:x_max,y_min:y_max,:]);
```

Not sure if it is correct, though it seems to be fine. What is the best way to generate such a patch for each superpixel? Moreover, is it possible to set the pixels in the patch, which do not belong to the superpixel, to black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regionprops` and access the patch coordinates via `region.bbox` as in

```
from skimage.data import astronaut
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.measure import regionprops
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

img = astronaut()
segments_slic = slic(img, n_segments=250, compactness=10, sigma=1, start_label=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
ax.imshow(img)

for region in regionprops(segments_slic):
    # draw rectangle around segmented coins
    minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle((minc, minr), maxc - minc, maxr - minr,
                              fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    # access patch via img[minr:maxr, minc:maxc]

plt.imshow(mark_boundaries(img, segments_slic))
plt.show()
```

This results in
[image: patches around superpixels]

Example adapted from [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html).

EDIT: Furthermore, with `region.image` you get a mask of your region to set the others to black.

Comment: This seems to miss the last segment. I am using `patches` list to collect the patches. I am printing using `print(f"The dataset length is: {len(patches)}\t The number of segments is {len(np.unique(segments_slic))}")` and I get `The dataset length is: 3883  The number of segments is 3884`. Also, at the bottom right of your image I think there is a rectangle missing. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce that. I have 193 regions, with values from 1 to 193 (inclusive). The one you think is missing is bigger and connected with the region to its top left (the lower right part of the rectangle is simply rendered outside the image).

Comment: Sorry, the output is `The dataset length is: 193  The number of segments is 194`. To reproduce, simply initialize a list with `patches = list()  ` and accumulate inside the `for` using `patches.append(img[minr:maxr,minc:maxc,:]);`

Comment: Ok, got it. The `0` labels are ignored in `regionprops()`. When I use the flag `start_label=1` in `slic()` it is resolved.